# How can I tell if someone is subscribed with a Paypal Subscribe Button?

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

So I have a PayPal Subscribe button all set up on my test website. It's a monthly subscription that a user would have to pay to gain access to their profile. I can't seem to get the logic right in my head. It might be my lack of knowledge with the PayPal classic API's, but everything I've searched has led me to a dead end. Using PHP and MySQL, how could I keep track of a user and make sure they are subscribed and/or if they cancel their subscription? Thanks for any help that may lead me to solving this, I appreciate it. If you need any of my code, I'll be glad to add it and edit, I just don't know if the code is needed for this question.

Comment: What code you have tried and error you are getting?

Comment: @Unknown I haven't really attempted to do this (code wise). I just can't seem to figure it out. By that I mean to organize a solution, get it out of my head, and try it. I just don't know where to start really. I was thinking of storing it in a boolean in the database perhaps?

Comment: Paypal uses email addresses as login names. So you have to remember in database which user has active subscription based on their email addr (user can use different email for your website and different for paypal!).

Comment: @Marki555, that's a good idea, but how would I know if their subscription has run out? As in, they've payed for the 1 year, but aren't renewing their subscription. Does paypal have anything to handle that, or should I email them with two links, one to resubscribe, and one to cancel the subscription?

Comment: They should be able to cancel the subscription also directly via Paypal. I guess you can configure paypal API with your URL which will be notified of this.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to look into that more.